# Segmentation fault with LAPACKE dgels_ in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, lapack

I want to solve the least square problem |Ax-b|->min with LAPACK's dgels_ in C, but I'm getting a segmentation fault error (I am aware that there was [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709335/lapack-dgels-segmentation-fault-11), but the code is quite different and the answers do not apply to my problem).
I already located the problem, it is right when dgels_ is executed.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

#define COL 3               
#define ROW 4

int main()
{
 char transa ='N';
 lapack_int m, n, nrhs, lda, ldb, info;
 m=ROW;
 n=COL; 
 nrhs=1;
 lda=ROW;
 ldb=ROW;
 double work[COL];

 double A [COL*ROW] = 
     { 1.1, 4.2, 1.7,   
       2.5, 2.1, 2.8,   
       3.4, 4.2, 8.5,   
       4.4, 5.2, 7.8 };

 double b[ROW] = 
     { 1.5,         
       2.1,         
       3.8,         
       3.4 };

 printf("test 1 \n");
 dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, work, 0, &info);
 printf("test 2 \n");

 return 0;
}
```

The first "test 1" is printed then there is the segmentation fault error.

Edit:
I tried to compile it before with values, i.e. using dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info).
However, then I get lots of error messages:

```
lapack_error.c: In function ‘main’:
lapack_error.c:32:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
             ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:21: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:24: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:27: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                           ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:36: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                                    ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:44: warning: passing argument 8 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                                        ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
      ^
lapack_error.c:32:58: warning: passing argument 11 of ‘dgels_’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info);
                                                          ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/lapacke.h:143:0,
                 from lapack_error.c:2:
/usr/include/lapacke.h:14793:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void LAPACK_dgels( char* trans, lapack_int* m, lapack_int* n, lapack_int* nrhs,
```

I then tried and look up a sample program and found [this one](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/lapack/codes/linear-c.html) (using sgesv but I figured it might be similar with dgels). And after rewriting dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info) to dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, work, 0, &info) there were no more error messages, so I thought this was the right way.

Comment: See the documentation at http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html#_function_list and then scroll down to DGELS. It seems you are calling it with lots of pointers where values would suffice. Also, turn warnings of your compiler on, so it would complain if you call it with the wrong type of arguments.

Comment: As for style: it is customary to have preprocessor macros in uppercase so you won't confuse them with macros. So for `#define col 3` rather use `#define COL 3`

Comment: Use a debugger, and examine the values of the parameters to `dgels_` after the segfault happens.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Yes, warnings are turned on, but gcc does not tell me any. 
In fact, I tried to compile it before with values, i.e. using dgels_(transa, m, n, nrhs, A, lda, b, ldb, work, 0, info). However, then I get lots of error messages (see edited original post).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I tried LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,transa,m,n,nrhs,A,lda,b,ldb) instead of dgels_ as it is shown in the documentation you linked. It compiles without warnings and there is no segmentation fault. However, it still doesn't work properly, which is a different question though.

Comment: @bnaecker: I tried [to use gdb with this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb) to access the values after the segmentation fault inducing line, but I only get:
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
    0x00007ffff76a44ed in dgels_ () from /usr/lib64/libreflapack.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` is not a legal value for the argument `lwork` of [dgels](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/dde/dgels_8f_source.html). Indeed, it must be a pointer to an integer in c, since all arguments are called by reference in fortran, while all arguments are called by value in c. Moreover, the value of `lwork` specifies the length of the array `work`, which [must be larger than 1](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/dde/dgels_8f_source.html): `LWORK >= max( 1, MN + max( MN, NRHS ) )`. The only exception is `lwork=-1`: in this particular case, the function returns to optimal size for the array `work` in `work[0]`.

For instance, the following lines can be tried:

```
    lapack_int lwork=n;
    if (m<n){lwork=m;}
    lwork=-1;
    double query;
    dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, &query, &lwork, &info);
    lwork=(int)query;
    printf("the optimal size is %d \n",lwork);
    work=malloc(lwork*sizeof(double));
    if(work==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"maloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, work, &lwork, &info);
    printf("test 2 \n");

    printf("%g %g %g\n",b[0],b[1],b[2]);
```

There are two calls to `dgels_` : the first returns the correct size of `work`. Then, `work` is allocated and `dgels_` is called again to perform the least square minimization.

The result can be different from what is expected by a regular C developper: [Fortran and C order of dimensions for multidimensional arrays are different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).The Lapacke wrapper provide the functions [`LAPACKE_dgels()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/da2/lapacke__dgels_8c.html) and [`LAPACKE_dgels_work()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/dc3/lapacke__dgels__work_8c.html) with arguments `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR`/`LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR`  and `transa`. Always make sure that you use the correct value for these arguments by performing a test! Try different values if it fails...

Here is a sample code based on yours showing different ways to call `dgels` through the Lapacke interface. It can be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -Wall`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

#define COL 3               
#define ROW 4

int main()
{
    char transa ='N';
    lapack_int m, n, nrhs, lda, ldb, info;
    m=ROW;
    n=COL; 
    nrhs=1;
    lda=ROW;
    ldb=ROW;
    double* work;

    double A [COL*ROW] = 
    { 1.1, 4.2, 1.7, 2.5,
    2.1, 2.8, 3.4, 4.2, 
    8.5, 4.4, 5.2, 7.8 };

    double b[ROW] = 
    { 39.3,         
    27.4,         
    29.3,         
    42.1 };

    printf("test 1 \n");
    lapack_int lwork=n;
    if (m<n){lwork=m;}
    lwork=-1;
    double query;
    dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, &query, &lwork, &info);
    lwork=(int)query;
    printf("the optimal size is %d \n",lwork);
    work=malloc(lwork*sizeof(double));
    if(work==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"maloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    dgels_(&transa, &m, &n, &nrhs, A, &lda, b, &ldb, work, &lwork, &info);
    printf("test 2 \n");

    printf("%g %g %g\n",b[0],b[1],b[2]);


    free(work);

    double Aa [COL*ROW] = 
    { 1.1, 4.2, 1.7,   2.5,
    2.1, 2.8, 3.4, 4.2, 
    8.5, 4.4, 5.2, 7.8 };

    double bb[ROW] = 
    { 39.3,         
    27.4,         
    29.3,         
    42.1 };

    //with lapacke
    info= LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,transa, m, n, nrhs, Aa, lda, bb, ldb);
    printf("%g %g %g\n",bb[0],bb[1],bb[2]);

    //

    double Aaa [COL*ROW] = 
    { 1.1, 4.2, 1.7,   
    2.5, 2.1, 2.8,   
    3.4, 4.2, 8.5,   
    4.4, 5.2, 7.8 };

    double bbb[ROW] = 
    { 16.3,         
    17.9,         
    45.8,         
    46 };

    //with lapacke
    info= LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'T', n, m, nrhs, Aaa, n, bbb, ldb);
    printf("%g %g %g\n",bbb[0],bbb[1],bbb[2]);


    double Aaaa [COL*ROW] = 
    { 1.1, 4.2, 1.7,   
    2.5, 2.1, 2.8,   
    3.4, 4.2, 8.5,   
    4.4, 5.2, 7.8 };

    double bbbb[ROW] = 
    { 16.3,         
    17.9,         
    45.8,         
    46 };

    // it is still possible to allocate the buffer yourself once for all if LAPACKE_dgels_work is used.
    // it can be useful if dgels is used many times, using the same transa, m,n,nrhs,lda,ldb but different A or b.
    info= LAPACKE_dgels_work(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'T', n, m, nrhs, Aaaa, n, bbbb, ldb,&query,-1);
    lwork=(int)query;
    printf("the optimal size is %d \n",lwork);
    work=malloc(lwork*sizeof(double));
    if(work==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"maloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    info= LAPACKE_dgels_work(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'T', n, m, nrhs, Aaaa, n, bbbb, ldb,work,lwork);
    free(work);
    printf("%g %g %g\n",bbbb[0],bbbb[1],bbbb[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and the correct code, it solved both my original problem with dgels_ and the one I had with LAPACK_dgels.